# What is the easiest way to setup LUKS on a new image?

Tags: luks

I am maintaining an RHEL7 image in a VM.  When I deploy it to a new machine, I will convert the VDI to a raw image, then DD it or I will use clonezilla.

I have a new requirement were some new machines require full disk encryption.  I've always used hardware encryptable drives which I just enable in the bios.

This is my first time using LUKS.  I have read there are several ways to encrypt, I can do the whole drive or each partition.  I think I would prefer to do the whole drive.

Should I image the drive first, then attempt to enable encryption?  Or is there a way to setup encryption first, then put the image on.

Note, after the image is installed, I typically use Gparted to resize the last partition to use up the rest of the disk space.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#LUKS_on_a_partition

You create an encrypted partition first, then copy data on top of it.

Comment: If I understand the wiki correctly, I will need to separate out the /boot into a separate partition, then create the partition table using cryptsetup recreating each of my partitions with the correct size.  I assume I would run cryptsetup off of a boot disc.  Then, how do I get my data in? Is clonezilla able to read the encrypted partitions to copy the data in?

Comment: You'll need to use cryptsetup to unlock the LUKS container (partition), which will produce a new block device (ex. /dev/mapper/luks-something) which encrypts/decrypts on-the-fly. You would then restore the image to that block device. Unfortunately, it seems like clonezilla only supports disks and partitions, so you would have to use partclone directly.

Comment: Would it be an option to set up and maintain a separate virtual machine on virtual encrypted storage? It'd double maintenance work, but deployment would be much easier (you may then want to re-encrypt the encrypted volumes to avoid having multiple machines sharing the same encryption key, but it'd likely be much simpler than setting up encrypted volumes on any new machine, extracting `/boot` from the original image, imaging the rest to an encrypted volume and updating the initramfs and bootloader configuration if needed).

Comment: That is what I'm trying to decide.  I've got 8 systems total that need to be imaged (and reimaged every few months).  Only 2 require encryption so it doesn't really seem worth the trouble to maintain two and make sure they are identical.